# Angular 3 similar controllers? How to combine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

Cheerio!

I just got another question. Using angular to build an app I stranded with 3 controllers very similar to each other. They differ in about 2-3 functions. All 3 controllers get elements from 3 different tables. Data handling inside the controller is always the same. Just the views differ a lot.

How could I combine them in a smart way. Like one main controller containing the logic used in all 3 and then 3 extension controllers or something like that?

(Using UI Router) I'd also be able to use just one state with a parameter to decide which data from which table should be used?!

Great Weekend for all of u.

Comment: You could use one main controller and can have different services . Based on state parameter you can which service to be called.

Comment: You should delegate all logic that is not directly updating the viewmodel to services/factories. Then all controllers can inject the service and share the logic. If you post some code examples I can give a more concrete answer.

Comment: do you mean angular 2?